# What is a good sketching tool for visualizing research ideas?

Tags: drawing, research

I am looking for an online tool, preferably, to sketch complex research ideas.

For instance, I want to complete project `X`. This project has some major component that need to be done and are somehow related to each other (imagine some arrows). Clicking on each of these major components will show some other sub-components that need to be done in order to complete this major component. Some of those sub-components could be just reading some papers. So I need to be able to put links in the diagram as well.

More ideally, I would like to have something like a citation library (something like `BibTeX`) and refer to those papers in different sub-components of different projects.

I wonder, is there a tool (preferably online) that provides me such things?

Comment: Org-mode/Emacs does all of this. Or look for a project management tool like Task Juggler. Or use pen and paper.

Comment: @henning Maybe I did not put enough emphasis on the *complexity* part. Well research ideas grow; therefore I need to be able to quickly add/remove stuff. I need some good graphical visualizations so that I can devise my own legend and continue making components with them. I want to write notes which might eventually turn into parts of a paper that I am going to write if the project works out. Although I have not used Org-mod or project management tools that much but I don't think they provide me such things. Do they? :)

Comment: You might want to look at Docear. Having said that, I will be voting to close the question as off topic

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [yWorks's yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) to you. It's simple to use, it has a lot of graph/sign and it's free... It's not only for idea-design, also it's supporting various uml diagrams too.

Answer (score 0):

[***Omni-graffle***](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle), [***mind-node***](https://mindnode.com/), [***lucidchart***](https://www.lucidchart.com/) all *might* apply, but... the question is pretty broad, even for the SW-Req SE.